# Redirect each domain non-www or http to www and https

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I want to redirect all each domain to www and https.
like:

```
http://example1.com  
http://example1.com.  
http://www.example1.com  
http://www.example1.com.  
https://example1.com  
https://example1.com.  
https://www.example1.com.
```

To:
https://www.example1.com

AND

```
http://example2.com  
http://example2.com.  
http://www.example2.com  
http://www.example2.com.  
https://example2.com  
https://example2.com.  
https://www.example2.com.
```

To:
https://www.example2.com

This is my code for domain1 in htaccess:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example1\.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example1\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example1.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example1\.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example1\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example1.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I check :
1. if address not has https AND if contains example1.com AND if not fully like www.example1.com or example1.com THEN redirect to https://www.example.com
2. if address has https AND if contains example1.com AND if not fully like example1.com THEN redirect to https://www.example.com

Comment: I suggest you use the regexes in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First replace the start by using Regex like this:

(I used C#, use just the regexes and the idea).

```
Regex.Replace(myString, @"^(https?:\/\/(www\.)?)?");
```

then replace the end:

```
Regex.Replace(myString, @"\.$");
```

### For example:

[Example Here](https://regex101.com/r/IXeegG/1)

```
http://example2.com.
```

will be replaced by the first Regex to:

```
https://www.example2.com.
```

and after the second Regex, to:

```
http://www.example2.com
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrire.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example1.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
</IfModule>
```

The above code snippet should work good for you.
Try it. If you have some issues, let me know in the comment

Comment: For example2 change the 5th line as :- `RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]`

Just change the *Domain Name*

Comment: It would be 
`RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example100258.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]`

Comment: It has to be a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
# domain example1.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example1\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example1.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# domain example2.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example2\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```